# Number of possible combinations by changing 3 places in a 9 characters long string with a specific N(6) of characters that can be used for a change

Tags: math, combinations

Let's say we have a string `a0d2bj5ew`.

We want to find all possible combinations by changing `3 places` in that string.

So it can be `a0[d]2bj[5]e[w]` or `a0[d][2][b]j5ew` and many many more.

The character set that we want to use for our change is also known, in this example it can be `012abc`, for example. So the `N` of that set of characters is `6`.

*By looking into all combinations by changing 3 places we also do the job for just one or two places simultaneously, so it can be also `a0[d]2bj[5]ew` or just `a0[d]2bj5ew`*

So the question what is the formula to calculate the total `N` of all combinations by working with the above mentioned criteria.

`a0d2bj5ew` string has `9` characters.

We change `3` all possible places.

And we use `012abc` as our set of characters that those places will be changed with, so the `N` is `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can choose 3 (K) positions from 9 (M) places by C(9,3) ways (C(M,K) or nCr, combination number)

Then we have to put 6 (N) possible characters onto these 3 (K) positions. There are 6^3 (N^K) ways, if we can use repeats (so we can get `a2a`), or A(6,3) ways if no repeats are possible (number of arrangements, combinations where order is important, so `a2b` is distinct from `2ab`)

Result:

```
C(M,K) * N^K = M! / (K!(M-K)!) * N^K
```

or

```
C(M,K) * A(N,K) = M!/(K!(M-K)!) * N!/(N-K)!
```

These formulas don't consider situations when replacement char is the same as old one

Comment: Thank You @MBo May I ask you why in the second formula we get `10080` and in the first one the result is different, it's `18144`.

Comment: Because these formulas correspond to distinct problem statements. If you can insert 3 a's in 3 places - use the first one